# Using the Inchoo PHP 7 patch on Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a client who wants to move his Magento site from PHP 5.2 to PHP 7.2, but it is running Magento 1.9.1. I see that the Inchoo patches only handle Magento 1.9.2 upwards.

What are the possible outcomes of using the patch on 1.9.1, and is there a feasible way to do it?

Note: the client resolutely refuses to update the store to 1.9.2 or upwards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inchoo patch is deprecated. Magento provides an official php7.2 compatibility patch: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240 
But as you can see, is compatible from magento 1.9.2. If your client refuses to update magneto core, the only solution is to write your own patch for magento 1.9.1

Comment: I suspected as much. That's way beyond me, I'm afraid. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.